# Is there a unmanipulatable device time?

Tags: android, datetime

Is there a clock in devices that returns always a certain time, independent from user time settings **and internet connection**?
Such a time would be very helpful when checking if a license has expired.

Comment: it is pretty hard without internet connection , you can save a time with Shared Preferences , when the user will open the app , if he has internet connection then a simple call will be done and the licence will be checked , another check that you can do is also to save the last open date , and at loading you check if date > last_opened_date , if not you can show a warrning message .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a clock in devices that returns always a certain time, independent from user time settings and internet connection?

No, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

The GPS clock is independent from system clock / time settings and network connection.

You can get a timestamp by requesting a location fix and accessing [`Location` `getTime()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getTime%28%29).

Of course, this is not bulletproof for license checking purposes as it can be spoofed as well. @CommonsWare's notes from comments are also worth considering:

> Note that this only works on devices that have GPS, where GPS is enabled by the user, where you can get a GPS signal, and for apps where you do not mind asking for the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission. Hence, this is not really "always", though it may suffice for many needs.

Comment: Note that this only works on devices that have GPS, where GPS is enabled by the user, where you can get a GPS signal, and for apps where you do not mind asking for the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission. Hence, this is not really "always", though it may suffice for many needs.

Comment: Thanks, it seems not possible to get offline a reliable time information.

Answer (score 0):

There is no time for this usecase.
[Here is a list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html) of the available types of time in Android:

> Three different clocks are available, and they should not be confused:
>
> System.currentTimeMillis() is the standard "wall" clock (time and
> date) expressing milliseconds since the epoch. The wall clock can be
> set by the user or the phone network (see setCurrentTimeMillis(long)),
> so the time may jump backwards or forwards unpredictably. This clock
> should only be used when correspondence with real-world dates and
> times is important, such as in a calendar or alarm clock application.
> Interval or elapsed time measurements should use a different clock. If
> you are using System.currentTimeMillis(), consider listening to the
> ACTION_TIME_TICK, ACTION_TIME_CHANGED and ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED
> Intent broadcasts to find out when the time changes.
>
> uptimeMillis() is
> counted in milliseconds since the system was booted. This clock stops
> when the system enters deep sleep (CPU off, display dark, device
> waiting for external input), but is not affected by clock scaling,
> idle, or other power saving mechanisms. This is the basis for most
> interval timing such as Thread.sleep(millls), Object.wait(millis), and
> System.nanoTime(). This clock is guaranteed to be monotonic, and is
> suitable for interval timing when the interval does not span device
> sleep. Most methods that accept a timestamp value currently expect the
> uptimeMillis() clock.
>
> elapsedRealtime() and elapsedRealtimeNanos()
> return the time since the system was booted, and include deep sleep.
> This clock is guaranteed to be monotonic, and continues to tick even
> when the CPU is in power saving modes, so is the recommend basis for
> general purpose interval timing.